# Line breaks in WMD editor

Tags: wmd-editor

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to handle line breaks with a WMD editor?
When a user hits enter in the textarea I want it to equate to a line break in the html.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

A single empty line will move your text to a new line. Is this what you mean?